# SQLite: CASE within FROM section

Tags: sqlite, case

I need to select the **MCUs** table if **UserID = 7** does not exist in the table. Please help me, what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    MCUs.MCUID
FROM
  CASE 
    WHEN ReqMCUDevs.UserID = 7 THEN
       MCUs

       INNER JOIN MCUDevs
        ON MCUs.MCUID = MCUDevs.MCUID

       INNER JOIN ReqMCUDevs
        ON MCUDevs.DevID = ReqMCUDevs.DevID
         AND ReqMCUDevs.Quantity >= MCUDevs.Quantity
    ELSE
       MCUs
  END
```

I need the resunt ot this query if **UserID=7** exists

```
SELECT
    MCUs.MCUID
FROM
    MCUs

    INNER JOIN MCUDevs
     ON MCUs.MCUID = MCUDevs.MCUID

    INNER JOIN ReqMCUDevs
     ON MCUDevs.DevID = ReqMCUDevs.DevID
     AND ReqMCUDevs.Quantity >= MCUDevs.Quantity
WHERE
    ReqMCUDevs.UserID = 7
```

and this query if not

```
SELECT
    MCUs.MCUID
FROM
    MCUs
```

database schema:
[image: database schema]

The easiest solution is to use two different queries

```
db = sqlite3.connect("..\\DB.db", isolation_level = None);
c = db.cursor()
#...

c.execute("SELECT UserID FROM ReqMCUDevs WHEN UserID = ?", (UserID,))

if c.fetchall() == []:
    c.execute("SELECT MCUID FROM MCUs")
else:
    c.execute("""SELECT MCUID FROM MCUDevs
JOIN ReqMCUDevs ON MCUDevs.DevID = ReqMCUDevs.DevID
    AND ReqMCUDevs.Quantity <= MCUDevs.Quantity
WHERE ReqMCUDevs.UserID = ?""", (UserID,))
```

but it is really not the answer

Comment: What is your actual problem? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: near "CASE": syntax error

Comment: This query does not make sense. What is the problem that you are trying to solve with it?

Comment: Show some example records, and the desired results.

Comment: If I find the required UserID, I need to make a conditional selection, but if not, I need to select the whole MCUs table

Comment: What do you mean with "conditional selection"? Show some examples!

Comment: `case` is an expression. It is neither table reference nor nested query, so it can't be used in context where one of those is needed.

Comment: [here is the ER](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D5DE8C0ED293E524!2297&authkey=!AHBadzSkp8OjySc&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png)
I've edited the post to add the desited things

Comment: In fact, I've solved my problem by checking the emptiness of the fetched list and using two separate queries. But it is too easy.

Answer (score 0):

CASE works only in expressions (i.e., to compute a value); it is not possible to change the basic structure of a query conditionally.

However, there are different mechanisms to get what you want.

First, the query with the joins does not actually return anything from the joined tables, so it is possible to rewrite it with a subquery:

```
SELECT Name,
       Price
FROM MCUs
WHERE MCUID IN (SELECT MCUID
                FROM MCUDevs
                JOIN ReqMCUDevs ON MCUDevs.DevID = ReqMCUDevs.DevID
                               AND ReqMCUDevs.Quantity >= MCUDevs.Quantity
                WHERE ReqMCUDevs.UserID = 7)
ORDER BY Price
```

Now, we want to ignore this WHERE filter if the subquery is empty.
This can be done with a separate check:

```
SELECT Name,
       Price
FROM MCUs
WHERE MCUID IN (SELECT MCUID
                FROM MCUDevs
                JOIN ReqMCUDevs ON MCUDevs.DevID = ReqMCUDevs.DevID
                               AND ReqMCUDevs.Quantity >= MCUDevs.Quantity
                WHERE ReqMCUDevs.UserID = 7)
   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT MCUID
                  FROM MCUDevs
                  JOIN ReqMCUDevs ON MCUDevs.DevID = ReqMCUDevs.DevID
                                 AND ReqMCUDevs.Quantity >= MCUDevs.Quantity
                  WHERE ReqMCUDevs.UserID = 7)
ORDER BY Price
```

Comment: So useful, thank you very much. I'm very new in SQL and I need to create a big system quickly. Your help is priceless.
If it's not difficunt for you, can you please explain what do you mean "the query with the joins does not actually return anything from the joined tables" ? It is tested and works OK... At first glance.

Comment: I think I understood what do you mean. It's a quite non-elegant code... Is there really no way to avoid the duplication?

Comment: I meant that none of the `MCUDevs` or `ReqMCUDevs` columns is returned by the outer query.

Comment: On programming language level, I've already made a subquery a separate variable... Strange for me that commonly used SQL language is so... Un-elegant.

Comment: SQLite is an *embedded* database, it is designed to be used in concert with your application's logic.

Comment: So is it alright for SQLite to do such things with separate queries and there are not much ways to avoid it while saving readability?

Comment: It works, it's faster, it's simpler. What do you think you gain by forcing these two things into one query?

Comment: More native... I guess it could be faster because everything is made by DBMS and there is no timewasting for sending results here and there. Moreover this thing seems VERY easy to made by one query. I'm surprised it's not so

Comment: An embedded database has no client/server communication overhead.